# Display all makred radio button and check boxs in a msgbox

Tags: vb.net

I have to display all selected radio buttons and check boxes in a msgbox when a button on the form is selected. The buttons and boxes are in several group boxes. I am not sure how to write that code.

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming WinForms...try something like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim results As List(Of String) = GetSelections()
        Dim msg As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, results)
        MessageBox.Show(msg)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetSelections() As List(Of String)
        Dim selections As New List(Of String)
        FindSelections(Me, selections)
        Return selections
    End Function

    Private Sub FindSelections(ByVal cont As Control, ByVal results As List(Of String))
        For Each ctl As Control In cont.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is RadioButton Then
                Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(ctl, RadioButton)
                If rb.Checked Then
                    results.Add(rb.Text)
                End If
            ElseIf TypeOf ctl Is CheckBox Then
                Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(ctl, CheckBox)
                If cb.Checked Then
                    results.Add(cb.Text)
                End If
            ElseIf ctl.HasChildren Then
                FindSelections(ctl, results)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```